# How to disable string interpolation when printing a variable with special characters?

Tags: perl, xml-twig, string-interpolation

In Perl, I'm using `XML::Twig` to read an XML file. Some of the attributes have text that look like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;Here is some text.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Some more text.
```

I'm reading this attribute into a variable named `$Body`. I'd like to print this variable out to a file without interpolating the special characters in the string, i.e., the output should look exactly like the input. My code looks like:

```
open (my $OUT, ">", "out.csv") or die $!;
print $OUT $Body;
```

However, when I look in `out.csv`, I see:

```
<p>Here is some text.</p>

<p>Some more text.
```

Instead, I'd like to see the original string:

```
&lt;p&gt;Here is some text.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA&;#xA;&lt;p&gt;Some more text.
```

I've tried the following with no success:

- `print $OUT '$Body';` Doesn't work, just shows "$Body"
- `print $OUT "$Body";` Doesn't work, same as no quotes.
- `print $OUT qw{$Body};` Doesn't work, just shows "$Body".

  Here is a complete example:

**tmp.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <node Body="&lt;p&gt;Here is some text.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Some more text."/>
</root>
```

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $t=XML::Twig->new();
$t->parsefile("tmp.xml"); 

my $root= $t->root;

open (my $OUT, ">", "out.csv") or die();

my @nodes = $root->children('node');   # get the para children
foreach my $node (@nodes){ 
    my $Body = $node->{'att'}->{'Body'}; 
    print $OUT $Body;
}
```

**Result:**

```
[dev@mogli:/swta] $ ./script.pl 
[dev@mogli:/swta] $ cat out.csv 
<p>Here is some text.</p>

<p>Some more text.
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't viewing the file in something thats converting it ? It could be working fine.

Comment: @Ian: I'm using vim to view the file, which doesn't convert these characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XML::Twig is doing the unencoding. Pass it the `keep_encoding` flag to prevent this:

```
my $t = XML::Twig->new(keep_encoding => 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Printing a scalar does not change it whatsoever<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
$ cat a.pl
$Body = '&lt;p&gt;Here is some text.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA&#xA&lt;p&gt;Some more text.';
open (my $OUT, ">", "out.csv") or die();
print $OUT $Body;

$ perl a.pl

$ cat out.csv
&lt;p&gt;Here is some text.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA&#xA&lt;p&gt;Some more text.
```

`$Body` doesn't contain what you think it does. XML::Twig properly returned the node's content, `<p>Here ...`. If the node is suppose to contain `&lt;p&gt;Here ...`, the XML file  should contain `&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Here ...`.

---

Notes:

1. Unless you instruct it to by adding an :encoding layer or some such, or unless you're on Windows which changes LF to CRLF by default.

Comment: Please see my updated question. In your case, you are creating `$Body`  with single quotes, which works. However, I'm reading `$Body` from an input file using XML::Twig. Maybe this is my problem; the read is doing the interpolation, not the write?

Comment: Adjusted accordingly.